# What is the best method to limit content to first 10 users, potentially using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to deliver content to the first 10 users of my application & then show an apology message to the subsequent users - I assumed logging users using MySQL and once it reaches 10 switching to the other content but can't find the best way...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Create a counter for the logged in user ... Store the user information in session ... once the counter reaches 10 and after that if a user try to login just redirect those user to page which says you cannot login right now

Comment: Who ever down voted this, is just mean. Grant it the quality of the question is vague at best, or low quality, but there was no means to make a down vote on it. This is a help forum.. help. I know.. look it up in google, ok.. let me ask you this, when you were a newb, would you know exactly what to look for to come up with this concept?

Comment: Thanks - I tried google, several different times but clearly wasn't wording the question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Im going to assume you want to do this time and time again, so I think the easiest way is to have a table that stores multiple rows on a per page load basis.. where if the row count for a particular campaign is less than whatever it is you wanna say is the cut off.

I would say just keep a count on a per campaign basis, but who knows you may want to know more about your users, maybe ip, time, other.. I'd say definately IP as I Can land on your page, refresh the page 10 times and kill it for anyone else, so you may want to take it where the IP is also something checking to limit that behavior. But you can track the time they landed, and all other stuff Ill keep it super simplistic for this though.

So basically you want to do..

Something like

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `load_count_table` WHERE campaignID = 1

PHP:
<?php
//note not sure which sql version your using, ie: mysql, mysqli, postgress
//so you will have to do conversion from query to php based array
//example $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($countOfrows < 10)
{

   if($row['userip'] !== $ipOfcurrentuser)
   {
      //you can get IP through the global $_SERVER
      //you will want to cycle over your sql array for all the userip's to compare
      //this if statement is checking to see if there is no match
      //no match found..
      include_once('special_page.php');
      query("INSERT INTO `load_count_table` (userip, campaignID, the_time) values('$ipOfcurrentuser', '1', 'sql formated datetime, timestamp')");
   }
   else
   {
      include_once('sorry_page.php');
   }
}
else
{
  include_once('sorry_page.php');
}
?>
```

Now for your db table schema based on what Ive got here you would want

columns: userip varchar(25), campaignID int(11), the_time datetime.

Comment: why database ? why not in client side?

Comment: you never must trust in the "client side...."

Comment: client side, be it session or cookie.. can be deleted, altered, or made completely usesless, or whatever.. be it by either so much as opening another browser, closing the current browser and coming back.. or, by someone going into the cookies and changing the value.. Cookies/Session are only good for certain minamalistic things, its what you do behind the scenes with those minimalistic things that matter, as you never want to put trust, faith, or heavy reliance on such mechanisms

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give that a try

Comment: No problem, its not a full solution to the notion, more than it is a stepping stone. I can think of a dozen ways to improve on that but Im not about to go writing that much code right now. Good luck, hope it all works out for ya

Comment: That's what i really needed, to be pointed in the right direction. Big thanks.

Comment: No problem, feel free to reach out in the future, always willing to help someone whiling to learn, when I can.